# How do i add a Mouse Over Tooltip to the icons in HTML

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have tried to add a mouse over tooltip to the icons, but they disappear anytime i create the Style .ion-android-hand:before {
I believe there is something i am missing, can anyone help me out on this?

```css
.ion-android-hand: {
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ion-android-hand:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 14%;
  left: 70%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  height: 10%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-style: normal;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wash-icons">
  <i class="ion-android-hand" data-text="Hand free triggering system"></i>
```

I have tried to add a mouse over tooltip to the icons, but they disappear anytime i create the Style .ion-android-hand:before {
I believe there is something i am missing, can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: First of all close the `div` tag

Comment: and remove `:` from `.ion-android-hand` declaration class

Comment: The tooltip deisplays but the Icon and images dissapear

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help you but it is a start based on what I understood from your problem.

Hover the red square As it is going to be use for phone I recommand using `:focus` as well as `:hover` as there is no mouse on phone. Hover do not work correctly on phones

```css
.wash-icons{
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
}
.wash-icons .ion-android-hand{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.wash-icons:hover .ion-android-hand, .wash-icons:focus .ion-android-hand {
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ion-android-hand:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  /*width: 14%;*/
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  /*height: 10%;*/
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-style: normal;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wash-icons">
  <i class="ion-android-hand" data-text="Hand free triggering system"></i>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
Process of the correction

1. Set visibility of `.ion-android-hand` to `visibility: hidden;` by default
2. Change the `visibility` to `visibile` when hover its parent `.wash-icons`

So hover parent show your "i"

Comment: Add some explanation to this answer so anyone can understand how it's work

Comment: Just did, but again, it is not sure that this is what he wants as it is not really clear

Answer (score 0):

Please hover **green circle** to see the **tooltip**

First set `visibility:hidden;` to **.ion-android-hand**

```
.ion-android-hand{
     visibility:hidden;
}
```

Then **`:hover`** the `wash-icons` to visible (Mobile phone not hover try **`:focus`** instead)

```
.wash-icons:hover .ion-android-hand,
.wash-icons:focus .ion-android-hand{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Also added some style to **wash-icons** for green circle.

```css
.wash-icons{
  background:#00cc00;
  border-radius:30px;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.ion-android-hand:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-style: normal;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ion-android-hand{
  visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wash-icons:hover .ion-android-hand,
.wash-icons:focus .ion-android-hand{
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wash-icons">me
  <i class="ion-android-hand" data-text="Hand free triggering system"></i>
</div>
```

**The top of Tooltip added arrow**

Demo here

```css
.wash-icons{
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnfUn.png);
  background-size:contain;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  padding:5px;
  position:relative;
}

.ion-android-hand:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 200px;
  left: 0;
  top:calc(100% + 5px);
  height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-style: normal;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ion-android-hand{
  visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wash-icons:hover .ion-android-hand,
.wash-icons:focus .ion-android-hand{
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ion-android-hand::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 5px);
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wash-icons">
  <i class="ion-android-hand" data-text="This is Toolip for Android icon"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is closed to mine but nice work, I just realize that :hover do not work on phone so I would recommand you to edit to add :focus. He did not mention but as his class "android"...

Comment: i used this  .ion-android-hand{
    
    visibility: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
}  and this .ion-android-hand:hover:before {
    visibility:visible;
    content:attr(data-text);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width: 15%;
    left: 70%;
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 7.5%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 125%;
    
         
}

Comment: it works on hover, but the icon disappears and moves with other icons.

Comment: you can add visiblity hidden `.ion-android-hand::before{ visibility: hidden; cursor: pointer; }`  then visible when hover `wash-icon:hover .ion-android-hand::before{ visibility: visible; cursor: pointer; }`

Comment: two methods here

Comment: `.ion-android-hand{visiblity:hidden;}` when hover `.ion-android-hand::hover{visiblity:visible;}`

Comment: Actually are you want like this.?